# How to get out of TTY and into X session

Tags: x11

I have a computer with Linux installed in it and when I log in there is only what seems to be code.

I had it working normal before, there were icons on the desktop and such, just like a windows computer, but now I can't seem to figure out how to get it back.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? What do you see? What does "the code" say?

Comment: What version of Linux? Ubuntu, presumably...

Comment: I started a similar thread about this here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249371/16920 with little more clarity about details.

Answer (score 2):

If you seem to be stuck in a blank console, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

This will take you to the GUI.

Comment: If X is running.

Comment: That is right. My assumption is that you hit the wrong keys in a very uncommon situation. and nothing changed in the installation or configuration of the machine.

Comment: If it's CentOS, he needs to use Ctrl-Alt-F1.  Again, assuming X is running.